# NGINX cannot forward https POST request to another port

Tags: nginx

I am running a NodeJS application and deployed using pm2 running on port 5000, this works fine with http requests. To get the https working I have created a reverse proxy in nginx to forward https request on port 5001 to forward to port 5000. It works fine if I disable the SSL, http request is correctly forwarded from port 5001 to port 5000 but https works only for GET method, but not for POST method.

```
server {
    listen 5001 default_server;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/xyz.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/xyz.key;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    root ~/mynodeapp; location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  proxy_buffering off; 
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
```

I need to be able to call my API endpoint running on port 5000 over SSL through port 5001

Comment: *"but https works only for GET method, but not for POST method."* - "does not work" is not useable error description. Please describe exactly what happens.

Comment: If I make a GET request to endpoint I get the response back as expected but when I try POST method I don't even see anything in logs

Comment: I have no idea how you make the GET and the POST request (browser, curl,  ...)? What kind of error you get in the client? Can you add debugging at the client side (like `curl -v ...`)? What is the exact request you are doing? In which log you are looking (nodejs, nginx)?

Comment: I am calling it from Postman

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
> ```

I have no idea what the purpose of these headers is since they should only be used when forwarding WebSockets - which also means only in the context of `GET`. Thus it is likely wrong and might explain the problems you have.

Comment: @OmkarFrozen: it is still unclear what exactly you've tried and what exactly did not work and what exactly happened when it did not work. Please see my comment on your question about the amount of detail which is needed to properly understand what you are doing and how you are failing.